# Connect Windows Phone 7 emulator with an Android phone

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, accelerometer

I am just wondering is there any way to connect accelerometer in my android phone to windows phone 7 emulator for testing my app?

I found one project using android accelerometer as mouse (https://sites.google.com/site/accelerometermouse/) and another project using AR for simulated input (http://accelkit.codeplex.com/), but I think it could be much easier to test using real phone (just with different OS).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there much point? Wont it behave differently on a real windows device anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator doesn't connect to wp7 hardware much less android.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Accelerometer Sensor Simulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202936%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) available as a part of the Windows Phone SDK, so you don't necessarily need hardware to test it with. Otherwise, you would have to build a service that connects from the phone to the desktop and passes XYZ acceleration data.